# Yii critetia addCondition and addInCondition + and/or operators

Tags: yii, criteria

Is it possible in a criteria to have AND & OR Operators between addCondition and addInCondition? I have something like this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

//if value is TRUE
$criteria->addCondition('t.value = TRUE');

//if value is False
$criteria->addCondition('t.value = FALSE');
$criteria->addInCondition('t.id',$array);
```

I don't know where I will put the operators. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

According the class reference (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail':

```
public CDbCriteria addInCondition(string $column, array $values, string $operator='AND')
```

The third parameter is the operator which will be added to the existing one, so for you it will be:

```
$criteria->addInCondition('t.id',$array, 'OR');
```

Comment: thanks for the info, i updated my question to clarify my question

Comment: You can use the second parameter for `addCondition()` to add the operator, or the third operator for `addInCondition()`. That's what you want.